# excel SUMIFS only on same date

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to create a formula in column K which sums **all cells that apply** , in column J, *only* when the following conditions are true:

- dates are the same in column A
- AND client name is the same in column B

For example, in cell `K2`, I want the sum of `J2+J3+J4` because `A2=A3=A4` and `B2=B3=B4`.

`K5=J5` only, because there are no other dates with the same client name.

`K6=J6+J7` because `A6=A7` and `B6=B7`.

What kind of formula would I use for this? I can't figure out how to do it with a SUMIFS.

[image: Photo of sheet]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In cell K2 put following formula:

`=IF(COUNTIFS($A$2:A2,A2,$B$2:B2,B2)=1,SUMIFS($J$2:$J$10,$A$2:$A$10,A2,$B$2:$B$10,B2),"")`

- Adjust row 10 value.  It will be last row of your actual data.
- Copy down as much you need.

**EDIT**

Uploaded file shows the cause behind formula not working correctly for you. It turned out to be whitespace characters in column B (names) data e.g.

- Cell B3: "Moe John" has a trailing space.
- Cell B10: Same case with "Doe Jane"

If you want to use above posted formula then all names shall be corrected. Or alternatively to deal with spaces you can adopt below approach.

`=IF(COUNTIFS($A$2:A2,A2,$B$2:B2,"*"&TRIM(B2)&"*")=1,SUMIFS($J$2:$J$28,$A$2:$A$28,A2,$B$2:$B$28,B2),"")`

Notice the change in `COUNTIFS` formula where `B2` is now replaced with `"*"&TRIM(B2)&"*"`.

Even such formula will take a beating if you have uneven whitespace characters in between your data. I'd suggest normalizing it as much as possible.

Comment: Thank you! I tried this and it seemed to be incomplete- it only summed J2 and J4, but not J3.

Comment: @thevulgar Can you check your cell J3 contents and formats? I don't see any reason why formula by itself will skip an intermediate cell.

Comment: J2=C2+D2, do you think this is preventing it from working?

Comment: Pasted numbers as values but its still not working. In K2 its only adding J2+J4 and not including J3.

Comment: @thevulgar I am not able to understand the issue. Is it possible to upload the file on a file sharing site (remove sensitive info if there)? I can then take a look.

Comment: Here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/gh3xavig77bsuj6/BillingDataAB.xlsx?dl=0

Comment: @thevulgar I see the issue now. Please refer edit above and see if it helps your situation.

Comment: @thevulgar Great! Thanks for feedback!

Answer (score 1):

I would try using a pivot table with:

- The names as row values
- The dates as the column values
- And funds received using SUM in the values column

***Edit***

Based on @pnuts comments here is how to get the values in column K. Put this in `K2` and drag down.

`=IF(OR(COUNTIFS($B$1:B3, B3) = 1, B3 = ""), SUMIFS($J$2:J2, $A$2:A2, A2, $B$2:B2, B2), "")`

This formula will give blank values until the formula finds a new client on a new date. However, I still think using pivot table is a better solution.

However, I still find the pivot table

Comment: Thank you! Based on this formula I'm just getting a value in K2 equal to J2.

Comment: You will if there is only one entry for that person on the specific date. E.g. Roe John and Loe John's sum will always be 189 and 191, because they only have one entry for their name on that date.